# Change 1 bit in file. What I did wrong?

Tags: language-agnostic, byte, bit

I had file with such content:

```
00 00 00 00 00
```

I had changed 1 bit. Changed file:

```
00 60 00 00 00
```

My teacher said, that I don't know what means bit. What I did wrong? Clarify this for me, please: file has 5 block (10 digits). Bit is `00`? Or bit is `0` — 1 digit of pair. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you first need to do some research into what a bit is (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit).

Comment: You changed two bits instead of one. A bit is a "binary digit" (0 or 1). A `6` is `110`. So you want from zeroes to something with `110` in it, which means two bits changed to 1. A byte is 8 bits and the numbers you show are probably hexadecimal (base 16) representations of bytes (two hex digits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in hexidecimal notation, then you have some terminology confusion.

```
 00  00  00  00  00
|__|          ^
  \           |
   byte     nibble
```

A byte is two nibbles, and a nibble is 4 bits.

```
Decimal   Hex     Binary
   0       0       0000    <- You went from here...
   1       1       0001
   2       2       0010
   3       3       0011
   4       4       0100
   5       5       0101
   6       6       0110    <- ...to here, a change in two bits of one nibble.
   7       7       0111
   8       8       1000
   9       9       1001
  10       a       1010
  11       b       1011
  12       c       1100
  13       d       1101
  14       e       1110
  15       f       1111
```

Comment: Nibble is bit, right? I opened file with 256 null bytes in hex editor. File contents is 16 such rows: `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. I have to change 1 bit now. `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01`: sequence of null bytes with one change bit. Right?

Comment: A nibble is 4 bits. Each "0" in your hex editor represents the bits "0000". The "1" represents the bits "0001". There is a difference of one bit between the two, yes.

Comment: `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` If I change 1 bit somewhere in the middle of that sequence, can I say that 1 bit is changed?

Comment: Yes, if you change a 0 nibble of a byte to any of 1, 2, 4, or 8 then you've altered only one bit. The 0 nibble is 0000, 1 is 0001, 2 is 0010, etc (see table in answer). On your typical computer you must read and write by bytes - a pair of nibbles. The easiest way would be an XOR operation with a power of 2 to flip a single bit of a single byte before writing it back.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what that notation means, but I'm assuming it's showing 5 *bytes* in hexadecimal notation.

These are *bytes*, 8 *bit*, in binary notation:

```
00000000
00000001
00000010
...
```

These are the same bytes in hexadecimal notation:

```
00
01
02
...
```

Hexadecimal notation goes from `00` to `FF`, binary notation for the same values from `00000000` to `11111111`. If you changed `00` to `60`, you changed `00000000` to `01100000`. So you changed *2* bits.

Answer (score 1):

You are viewing the file in a hex editor/viewer. Each digit is a hexadecimal digit consisting of four bits in binary. The fact that you went from `00` to `60` means that you changed two bits in one of the hex digits. If you were viewing in binary mode, you wouldn't see anything other than 0s and 1s.

```
hex 0  == binary 0000
hex 6  == binary 0110
```

I would recommend reviewing binary and hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Ty. I wrote you data already in hexadecimal notation. So, in my changed file I had changed only 1 bit, right?

Comment: No, you changed two bits. Going from `0000b` to `0110b` is a change of two bits.